# Source for MODERN combinatorial topology

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I have basic background in algebraic topology (Up to and including homology chapters of hatcher).

I recently saw a couple of papers that seem very interesting-

1. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312482.pdf
2. http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~meshulam/eprints/exp_final.pdf
3. http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~meshulam/eprints/torsion.pdf

These all seem to be giving combinatorical conditions for bounds on dimensions of homologies, I'm descrinbing this super vaugly and probably incorrectly because I haven't read the details of the proofs.

I tried searching for an introductory book but searching combinatorial topology or homology gives me classical intro books for alg. topology.

Is there a good reference?

Added as a commentor recommanded-

I am like a child asking "I know group theory, why is there no quintic formula?", and the answer I want is read about field theory (see this book), then galois theory (see this book).

My point is I feel like this is a whole well known subject and I just don't know what the name is so I can't find good surveys.

Comment: Your question is indeed vague and unclear. For example, I'm not sure where you came up with the term "combinatorial topology"; I searched all three papers for the term "combinatorial" and it barely comes up. These three papers are more about graph theory, particularly about analysis on graphs. I suggest that reading their introductions and tracing back through their citations and bibliographies (what is known in some other fields as "research") is a good way to find the references you want.

Comment: @LeeMosher  I'm not sure where I came up with the term either, I think I just thought that's the appropriate name since it concerns homologies of graphs and hypergraphs? I am vauge since as mentioned I don't understand much about their definitions. Of course I tried to see if any of them references a book or a survey, but that's not the case, only earlier papers. Thus, I thought that posting on a public form, a person who is familiar with the subject would recognize it and be able to reference me a book.

Comment: On the first two pages of the first paper you linked, I found the concept of the laplacian of a graph. I searched on Google for "laplacian of a graph", and the first hit looks like a good wikipedia page on that topic.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm familiar with the laplacian in expanders application, but on the wikipedia page there is no mention of a homology theory. Searching homology of laplacian gets me to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.2712.pdf . If you're familiar with the topics the paper deal with, do you think this is a good introduction that leads to the relevant concepts? I don't think you understand the point of my post. I am like a child asking "I know group theory, why is there no quintic formula?", and the answer I want is read about field theory (see this book), then galois theory (see this book).

Comment: That helps to clarify your question greatly (and the question itself would be improved with that information included into it).